# Si almaceno un string en una variable, como uso dicho string como variable?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

La pregunta parece un trabalenguas pero hay una cosita de javascript que quisiera hacer y no sé bien como funciona:

Yo tengo una objeto:

```
const data = {
      label: "Ambientes",
      value: "room_amount",
      action: "roomAmountAction",
    };
```

Y quiero acceder a un valor guardado en `store.state.filtros.room_amount` (que es un objeto distinto, de la tienda de vuex)

Pero también tengo objetos como

```
 const data2 = {
      label: "Baños",
      value: "bathroom_amount",
      action: "bathroomAmountAction",
    };
```

Entonces ahora quisiera acceder a `store.state.filtros.bathroom_amount`

Y así sucesivamente.

Existe una manera de llegar a armar algo dinámico como `store.state.filtros.DATA.VALUE` (claramente así no funciona pero es un ejemplo para hacerme entender). Hay alguna forma de combinar nombres de variables de esta manera para llegar al `store.state.filtros.` que yo quiera de manera dinámica?

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. Los objetos no se construyen así en JS (los paréntesis no se usan). Y se accede a los datos usando los nombres de clave, que están a la izquierda. Por ejemplo, con `data.ref.value` obtendrías el valor: `bathroom_amount` que es el valor asociado a la propiedad `value` del objeto.

Comment: Haz esta prueba por ejemplo: `const data = { ref: { label: "Baños", value: "bathroom_amount", action: "bathroomAmountAction", } }; console.log(data.ref.value);` Ese es un objeto JS válido y accedes a los valores (datos de la derecha) mediante las propiedades (datos de la izquierda).